# process: exec: "jupyterhub-singleuser": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: jupyterhub

I'm trying to spin up JupyterHub on EKS with multiple profiles as per the [docs](https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/stable/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html#using-multiple-profiles-to-let-users-select-their-environment).

The thing is that whenever I try to customize the image as by the [docs](https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/stable/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html#customize-an-existing-docker-image) and spin up the environment, I get the error

```
Error: failed to start container "notebook": 
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: 
OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec:
"jupyterhub-singleuser": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

When I log in the container (not using EKS, because it gets stuck in CrashBackLoop), I could see that the $PATH was did missing the command, but even though fixing the PATH in Dockerfile, the startup in EKS fails. Running from docker itself (docker run

Has anyone ever come accross this and could shed a light ?

The Dockerfile is

```
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook:latest

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . {HOME}/my_project
```

I did found someone who stumbled upon the same issue [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/cant-use-custom-docker-image-for-jupyterhub/10371/3), but it returned the same error

Comment: It seems tha a simple addition of a new library breaks the startup